# Add data into more than 1 table from Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

I have two table `donor` and `address`.

I want to insert all the basic details in `donor` table and address into `address` table with donor id.

[image: donor]

[image: address]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Donor;

class DonorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('donor.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $donor = new Donor;
        $donor->salutation = $request->input('salutation');
        $donor->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $donor->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $donor->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $donor->phone = $request->input('phone_home');
        $donor->mobile = $request->input('phone_mobile');
        $donor->email = $request->input('email');
        $donor->occupation = $request->input('occupation');
        $donor->is_active = $request->input('status');
        $donor->is_deleted = 0;
        $donor->created_by = 1;
        $donor->updated_by = 1;
        $donor->save();


        return redirect('/donor')->with('success', 'Hurray!! New donor Created.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

How to enter details into `address` table.

Comment: This is not very clear, and is likely to be put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a donor has an address, and the address is a unique item which has its own table, you should create a model for Address, and use the eloquent relationships to connect these two together.

You can read more about eloquent relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

So in your Donor model, you would go something like this:

```
public function address(){
     return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

And in your Address class:

```
public function donor(){
     $this->belongsTo('App\Donor');
}
```

So, in your donor controller, you'll create a new instance of address, and connect it to the donor:

```
$address = new App\Address;
... Your stuff to populate the address
$donor->address()->save($address);
```

Note: this is not the entire code to achieve what you want, and I wrote it from memory. You should do some research to figure it out.